# Lua: Saving and opening a two dimensional table indexed by key

Tags: lua, lua-table

Apologizes if the semantics is erroneous in my question, but the code below should explain what my goal is.

**I've created a table like so:**

```
local a1 = {}
a1.hammer = {
  price = 10,
  quantity = 5,
  category = "tools",
}
a1.saw = {
  price = 15,
  quantity = 4,
  category = "tools",
}
a1.screwdriver = {
  price = 4,
  quantity = 12,
  category = "tools",
}
```

Printing the contents of this table gives:

```
 {hammer = {price = 10,
                                      quantity = 5,
                                      category = "tools"},
                            saw = {price = 15,
                                   quantity = 4,
                                   category = "tools"},
                            screwdriver = {price = 4,
                                           quantity = 12,
                                           category = "tools"}}
```

**Question 1:** How do I access the price of the screwdriver (ie. field of a table of a table)

**Question 2:**
How do I:

1. Save table a1 to a file
2. Open the file and import the table the next time I run the application

*Note: local a2 = a1 returns nil for a2 rather than assigning the reference of a1 to a2. There's an issue here...*

Comment: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SaveTableToFile

Comment: Re 1: I guess you know how to access a field of a table already. Then just do it twice.

Comment: Can you show the line of code that successfully assigns the hammer's price to variable x? It seems obvious but it doesn't work for me. Also local a2 = a1 doesn't seem to successfully copy the reference of a1 to a2. a2 returns nil.

Comment: I'm not asking how to copy by value vs copying by reference. That's irrelevant. <message I'm replying to was deleted by user>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Luke Allison

I may have an answer to your first question:

> Question 1: How do I access the price of the screwdriver (ie. field of
>   a table of a table)

you can try this code:

**print( a1["screwdriver"]["price"] )**

Result = 4.

As for the second question you should have a look at the link in the comments above.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I found that a1.screwdriver.price seems to work also :)

Comment: thank you for accepting my answer! really appreciated.